# Returning values from dynamic SQL by using sp_executesql with an output variable (Or) Error in appending the variable data at the end name dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I just face a problem while working on a stored procedure,

My situation is as below,

I'm calling a stored procedure inside another stored procedure like for example,

```
EXEC    [SP_ADMIN_INSERT_ITEM_STOCK_DETAILS]
                        @stk_tran_no =  @cash_purchase_no,
                        @stk_tran_date = GetDate(),
                        @tran_type = 'Cash Purchase',
                        @item_code =  @item_code,
                        @quantity = @quantity
```

Currently in the above code we are passing current date to the parameter @stk_tran_date.

But now I need to pass date to @stk_tran_date by fetching that from some other table like,

```
select  @stk_tran_date  = Convert(datetime,cash_purchase_date,103) from Cash_Purchase_14  where cash_purchase_no = 'GOH-9/2014'
```

If you observe my table name is like Cash_Purchase_14 where 14 is a dynamic value which changes every year, as this is 2014 financial year so it looks like Cash_Purchase_14, next year it will be Cash_Purchase_15.

Because of this i use to write these quires first as string then I'll execute them as shown below,

```
  declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)
  set @SQL =N' Declare @cash_purchase_date1 datetime 
  set @cash_purchase_date1 = (select  cash_purchase_date from Cash_Purchase_'+ @Financialyearpart +'  where cash_purchase_no = ''' + @cash_purchase_no + ''')
                            print @cash_purchase_date1'

  exec executesql @SQL
```

But I need the value of the variable @cash_purchase_date1 outside this block like below,

```
EXEC    [SP_ADMIN_INSERT_ITEM_STOCK_DETAILS]
                        @stk_tran_no =  @cash_purchase_no,
                        @stk_tran_date = @cash_purchase_date1,
                        @tran_type = 'Cash Purchase',
                        @item_code =  @item_code,
                        @quantity = @quantity
```

but it is giving an error like, "declare the variable @cash_purchase_date1"

In Other case i tried like calling the stored procedure in side the string like,

```
SET @SQL =' Declare @cash_purchase_date1 datetime
                        set @cash_purchase_date1 = (select  cash_purchase_date from Cash_Purchase_'+ @Financialyearpart +'  where cash_purchase_no = ' + @qt + @cash_purchase_no + @qt +')
                        print @cash_purchase_date1
                        EXEC    [SP_ADMIN_INSERT_ITEM_STOCK_DETAILS]
                        @stk_tran_no = ' + @qt + @cash_purchase_no + @qt +',
                        @stk_tran_date = @cash_purchase_date1,
                        @tran_type = ''Cash Purchase'',
                        @item_code = ' + @qt + @item_code + @qt +',
                        @quantity = ' + @quantity

exec executesql @SQL
```

In this scenario the value of @cash_purchase_date1 is not replacing it simply retains the same.

Please help to get the value of the variable outside the block.

Or

How can I append the value 14 at the end of the table name dynamically using a variable.

I Tried like

```
Declare @cash_purchase_date1 datetime
set @cash_purchase_date1 =  cash_purchase_date from Cash_Purchase_+ @Financialyearpart
```

I think i made the problem bit complicated while explaining. Please help me in solving the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return values from dynamic sql by using `sp_executesql` with an `output` variable:

```
 declare @SQL nvarchar(4000);
 declare @cash_purchase_date datetime;

    set @SQL = N'select @cash_purchase_date = cash_purchase_date from Cash_Purchase_' + @Financialyearpart + ' where cash_purchase_no = ''' + @cash_purchase_no + '''';

    exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@cash_purchase_date datetime OUTPUT', @cash_purchase_date = @cash_purchase_date OUTPUT;
```

I think this will solve your problem.